# UIDatePicker and American/Canadian Timezone messing Up NSFetchRequest filter by Dates

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uidatepicker

I have a `UITabBarController` with two tabs (Timeline and Dates); both of which are `UITableViewControllers`. The user adds in information to these table views by tapping on a `UINavigationBar` button and then filling in information like Name, Event, Amount and Date. The first three are `UITextFields` and the date is a `UIDatePicker`. With the information saved to `Core-Data`, the `UITableViewController` gets updated using `NSFetchedResultsControllers`.

The model of CoreData is a Transaction Entity with a relationship to the Years Entity. I also have a Years Entity for checking the dates elsewhere (but more than just the years).

The second tab is a "Dates" tab which filters simply on the Years from the date, so if a user has 5 entries for the year 2014, it will only show 2014 once and then when the user clicks on the 2014 cell, they'll see all entries where the year = 2014. The same applies for other years.

**Problem**

I'm in the United Kingdom locale but my Mac that I coded the app on is in the US locale and I've just noticed a massive issue.

If you change the timezone to Singapore, or Asia (somewhere in front of UK in time) on the devie, the dates tab remains the same with what you left it as. However, if you change it to New York on the phone, or Mexico, or Canada (basically anytime behind the UK), then the Dates tab gets messed up with each year going down by one.

What I mean by this is, if you have 2014, 2013, 2012 in the Dates Tab and you're in the UK region, if you go to the New York timezone and go into the app, it now shows 2013, 2012 and 2011.

What is going on?

Here's some code in the "Save" Method of the Add Entry:

```
NSCalendar *yearCal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *yearComponent = [yearCal components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:self.datePicker.date];
[yearComponent setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
NSDate *selectedYear = [yearCal dateFromComponents:yearComponent];

// Calling the year category to check whether it exists.
Years *years = (Years *)[Years matchingYear:selectedYear inManagedObjectContext:context];
transaction.years = years;
```

This calls a category on the Year `Entity`:

```
+ (Years *)matchingYear:(NSDate *)enteredYear inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    Years *years = nil;

    // Creating a fetch request to check whether the year already exists, calling from the Add/DetailViewController.
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Years"];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"yearOfEvent = %@", enteredYear];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"yearOfEvent" ascending:YES];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *matchedYears = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (!matchedYears)
    {
        // No errors to handle
    }
    else if (![matchedYears count])
    {
        // If the year count is 0 then create it
        years = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Years" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        years.yearOfEvent = enteredYear;
    }
    else
    {
        // If the year exists, return it.  
        years = [matchedYears lastObject];
    }
    return years;

}
```

My UIDatePicker is set to the current date, so the user cannot pick a date in the future.

Here's the fetchResultsController code for the date tab:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Years" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    fetchRequest.entity = entity;
    NSPredicate *d = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"transactions.years.@count !=0"];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:d];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"yearOfEvent" ascending:NO];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sort];
    fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20;
    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

In my Save method, I notice I'm setting the timezone to UTC and the reason I did this was because if I didn't, when I went to another country and changed my timezone, it would add "2014" for each entry of 2014 in the Dates tab which was obviously wrong. But this is of course causing some issues here.

**Requirement**

I simply require the ability to keep the Dates tab the same, regardless of which timezone I'm in.

**Key Points**

There are a few reasons why the format is saved as it is in the Years, etc and that can't be changed because it impacts the entire app. The UIDatePicker is set to a UK Locale in the Storyboard and there are a few reasons for that. However, even with the locale set to "Default", the same issue occurs. Timezones in America and Canada remove a year, so 2014 becomes 2013, 2013 becomes 2012, 2012 becomes 2011 in the Dates tab. That's what doesn't make sense to me.

Any guidance on this would be really appreciated!

Comment: You should save NSDate rather than D, M, Y...

Comment: Thanks @Larme - There a few reasons why it's saved as that format instead of NSDate, but I'm not sure if that's what's causing the issue here because it works in every timezone, except America and Canada.. do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: @Tom Harrington explained why it's "better". Plus, you could easily use `NSPredicate` and check for year, creating dates with `NSDateComponents`, if that what may scare you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is going on?

What's going on is that your requirement of keeping dates consistent regardless of timezone is not nearly so easy as you'd like. It's like this:

- `NSDate` has no concept of time zone. It's basically an object wrapper for `NSTimeInterval`, measuring time since a reference date in UTC.
- When you convert an `NSDate` to something human-readable, a time zone applies to the conversion. It has to apply, because when you ask for the date corresponding to the `NSDate`, you have to answer the question, *the date, where, exactly*?

Your initial save code sets you up for this problem:

```
NSCalendar *yearCal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *yearComponent = [yearCal components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:self.datePicker.date];
[yearComponent setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
NSDate *selectedYear = [yearCal dateFromComponents:yearComponent];
```

If the selected date is today, the final NSDate is 410227200 seconds since the reference date, which in UTC corresponds to 00:00:00 on 1 January 2014. In time zones east of UTC it's one or more hours later, which is still 2014. In time zones west of UTC it's one or more hours earlier, which is still 2013. Every other detail of your problem stems from this fact.

If you care about the year, the best solution is to **store the year**, not an `NSDate`. Store 2014, 2013, 2012, etc as integers rather than as values implied by `NSDate`.

Incidentally this part of your question is completely irrelevant:

> I'm in the United Kingdom locale but my Mac that I coded the app on is in the US locale and I've just noticed a massive issue.

What matters is the time zone on the device running the code, not the zone on the device used to compile and link that code.

Comment: Thanks Tom - this is absolutely brilliant and it makes a lot of sense. I do have an issue with the migration of the Core Data model in the other question, but for this question, this makes perfect sense and I couldn't have found a better solution online. I'm comfortable with NSStrings and Core data (I'm fairly new to development), so could I just simply use an NSString to extract the year and compare that, or does it have to be an integer? Logically that makes sense, but I want to ensure I get it working with an NSString first, etc

Comment: Integers will sort a lot faster (compare one numeric value vs. compare N characters). Strings will work, but in cases where the strings have different length they don't always sort in numeric order.

Comment: Thanks Tom - that's brilliant - really appreciate your assistance with this